# How much information does the Hamiltonian contain in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian, observables

Given a Hamiltonian, let's say of a many-body system, through the Schrodinger equation,in principle we can find the eigenfunctions and their corresponding eigenvalues (spectrum). Now given an arbitrary observable (not necessarily comutating
 with the Hamiltonian),  we wish to work out its eigenvalues (spectrum). In the latter case we have to average the observable over the Hamiltonian's eigenfunctions. In this respect it seems that all the information of the physical system flows from the Hamiltonian to its eigenfunctions. My question is then, if it is possible to find a mathematical relationship between the Hamiltonian and the observable's spectra without using the Hamiltonian wavefunctions, but only a functional  relation between the two observables.

Comment: [You mean something like this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I knew this stuff, but I would keep the time evolution aside, if it is possible.

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking - what do you mean by "the information flows from the Hamiltonian to its eigenfunctions"? And what about the Heisenberg picture is not satisfying?

Answer (score 1):

The spectrum of a generic observable, especially if it doesn't commute with the Hamiltonian, is not determined by averaging it on the eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian. The way the spectrum is determined is by the usual means of spectral theory, that is you look for those values $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ (observables are assumed to be self-adjoint operators, hence the spectrum will be contained in $\mathbb R$) for which $O-\lambda I$ is not invertible in the set of bounded operators on the representation Hilbert space $H$, where $O$ is the observable in question in a certain representation and $I$ is the identity over $H$.

More abstractly, if you are given the full C*-algebra of observables then you can characterise the spectrum of an operator as the set of values $\omega(O)$, where $\omega$ is any state from the state space of the C*-algebra that is such that the uncertainty $\Delta_\omega(O)$ vanishes.

On the other hand it is true that one can encode the information of the Hamiltonian by means of its spectral decomposition, which gives spectrum and (generalised) eigenspaces.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Please can you give me any reference? Also can you explain your last sentence in different way? I wish to understand it better. Thanks again.

Comment: But if I don't need the Hamiltonian which describes the physics of the system under study, it seems to me difficult to work out the spectrum of any other observable. There should be a correlation between the Hamiltonian and the observable like it is evident in Heisenberg picture.

Comment: The spectral decomposition is just the representation
$$H = \int_{\mathbb R} \lambda\text dE(\lambda),$$
where $E$ is the spectral measure associated to $H$. In order to have a concrete example, suppose that the spectrum of $H$ is discrete, then each projection $\text dE$, where $\text dE$ is evaluated between two consecutive points in the spectrum, say $\lambda$, is the projection onto the $\lambda$-eigenspace. As for the role of the Hamiltonian, this is similar to classical mechanics in the sense that it gives a time evolution, i.e. a dynamics either on the state space or between observables

Comment: Given a particular system, one has to deals with a proper Hamiltonian. Thus from a physical point of view, the information stored in the Hamiltonian should affect any observable's spectrum in some way.

Comment: @user60565, that's not true. Spectrum is purely mathematical property of the operator in question. If the operator has no relation to the Hamiltonian, their spectra have no relation either. Only if you have something like, say, $\hat{A}=\hat{H}^2$ or generally any function of  $\hat{H}$, there could be some relation between the spectra.

Comment: Indeed, by the spectral theorem, the spectrum of $H$ and any continuous function $f$ of $H$ are related by $f(\sigma(H))=\sigma(f(H))$. In a von Neumann algebra one can then go as far as considering measurable functions rather than just continuous. But for general operators there is no relation between spectra in principle.